# Trying to always log my command output from terminal, but the script command is looping

Tags: bash

So I am trying to use the `script` command to *always* log the output of my commands (this is for work); however, when I place the `script` command in my `~/.zshrc` file (since I'm using zshell), it seems that it continuously runs when I open zsh.

So here's what my `~/.zshrc` file looks like towards the bottom:

```
LOGDATE=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S_%p.tlog")
script $LOGDATE
```

and then when I open a new terminal, this is what I get:

```
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_05_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_05_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_05_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_05_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_05_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_06_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_07_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_08_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_08_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_08_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_08_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_08_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_08_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_08_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_08_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_08_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_08_AM.tlog
Script started, file is 01_16_2019_07_15_08_AM.tlog
```

and this runs until I hold ctrl-c to stop it from doing it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow's scope is limited to questions about writing code. For UNIX tool configuration or use, consider [unix.se] or SuperUser.

Comment: That said, what you're doing wrong is starting script from your rc. That file is sourced when a shell starts, and when you run script, it... starts a new shell to log the output of. Generally speaking, it shouldn't be involved from a rc file at all, but if you *are* going to do that, you need guardrails to prevent recursion.

Comment: Ahhh... I gotcha. Makes sense. Not sure why I didn't even think of that, smh! Much appreciated

Comment: Frankly, there are other tools built more to purpose for logging console sessions for security or auditing purposes that don't require cooperation of the user for whom that logging takes place; I'd be selecting a different tool altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't advise using `script` in shell init files at all (and our sister site [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit for a wider question about what to use instead), but a way to avoid your narrow issue is to use an environment variable as a sigil that logging is already taking place, and avoid starting a new session should it be set:

```
if ! [ -n "$script_log" ]; then
    script_log=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S_%p.tlog")
    export script_log
    script "$script_log"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. Found another solution that I ended up using here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25639/how-to-automatically-record-all-your-terminal-sessions-with-script-utility, but I appreciate your help as well!

Comment: The `ps`-grepping approach is pretty awful -- I'd personally avoid that one in favor of something based on auditd (particularly if you care about the commands run more than their output; using auditd to trace execve syscalls will track commands run through means that don't generate a shell or any console-level trace) or sysdig (the sysdig approach lets you run just one process to trace every session on your system, or at least, every session that matches your filters).

Comment: Gotcha. Sounds great. I appreciate the input and the solution here man! Going to go with this one.